# Relationship between closure systems and closure operators

Tags: abstract-algebra

Following picture is from *Ordered Sets and Complete Lattices* by Hilary A. Priestley. My question is how to prove part $3$?

So, in part $1$ there is a map $f \colon C \mapsto {\mathcal L}_C$ and in part $2$ there is a map $g \colon {\mathcal L} \mapsto C_{\mathcal L}$.

So, it is needed to prove that $f(g(\mathcal{L})) = \mathcal{L}$ and $g(f(C)) = C$ for every $\mathcal{L}$ and $C$, right? How to do this?

[image]

Comment: You make use of the facts that for any $A \subseteq X, C(C(A)) = C(A)$. and if $A \subseteq A'$ then $C(A) \subseteq C(A')$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first half of (iii) you want to start with a closure operator $C$ on $\wp(X)$. Then by definition $\mathfrak{L}(C)=\{A\subseteq X:C(A)=A\}$, and for each $A\subseteq X$

$$C_{\mathfrak{L}(C)}(A)=\bigcap\{B\in\mathfrak{L}_C:A\subseteq B\}\,,$$

and we want to show that this is actually just equal to $C(A)$. If $A\subseteq B\in\mathfrak{L}_C$, then $C(A)\subseteq C(B)=B$, so $C(A)\subseteq C_{\mathfrak{L}(C)}(A)$. For the opposite inclusion, note that $C\big(C(A)\big)=C(A)$, so $C(A)\in\mathfrak{L}_C$, and $A\subseteq C(A)$, so $C_{\mathfrak{L}(C)}(A)\subseteq C(A)$.

For now I’ll leave it at that and let you take a crack at the second part yourself.

Comment: So $\mathcal{L}_{C_{\mathcal{L}}} = \{ A \subseteq X | C_{\mathcal{L}}(A) = A \}$ 
and $C_{\mathcal{L}}(A) = \bigcap \{ B \in \mathcal{L} | A \subseteq B \}$.
Assume $A \in \mathcal{L}_{C_{\mathcal{L}}}$, then $C_{\mathcal{L}}(A) = A$ and $A \subseteq B \in \mathcal{L}$...

Comment: @onm: $\bigcap\{B\in\mathfrak{L}:A\subseteq B\}=C_{\mathfrak{L}}(A)=A$, so $A\in\mathfrak{L}$, since $\mathfrak{L}$ is complete. Thus, $\mathfrak{L}_{C_{\mathfrak{L}}}\subseteq\mathfrak{L}$. If $A\in\mathfrak{L}$, then certainly $A=\bigcap\{B\in\mathfrak{L}:A\subseteq B\}=C_{\mathfrak{L}}$, so $A\in\mathfrak{L}_{C_{\mathfrak{L}}}$.